# std::list c++ is sequential then how it can take constant time for insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence

Tags: c++, std

in c++ reference i read "Lists are sequence containers that allow constant time insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence, and iteration in both directions."
 my doubt is if it is sequential then how it can take constant time to delete and insert a node.Any way we have to traverse sequentially to reach that node . Deleting node depends on its position

Comment: Given that you have the iterator to the specific node, insertion/deletion takes constant time. However if you don't have that particular iterator, you have to iterate till that position to do so, which is not constant time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O(1) referst to the complexity for inserting/erasing nodes provided you *already have a handle (in the form of an iterator) to that node*. Obtaining an iterator to the *i*th element of a list given an iterator to the first one is O(N).

This is quite often overlooked when judging the relative merits of `std::list` vs. say, `std::vector`. But note that both inserting and erasing elements return iterators that can be used for further insert/erase operations.

Comment: Just want to add that using the base `insert()`, `emplace()` and `erase()` functions return iterators to the inserted or deleted position. However, `pushFront()`, `popFront()`, `pushBack()`, and `popBack()` all return void. So someone wanting to enable constant time deletion for a given element must not add the element to the list using `pushXXXX()`.

Answer (score 5):

Insertion **before a given node**(lets call it `pos`) or **as last node**  or deleting a **given node** is a constant time operation.

`std::list` can be implemented as doubly linked list. Sequence containers should not be confused with contiguous memory requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Because the list is not sorted. If you look closely, the actual function for putting elements in the list is `list::insert(hint, element)` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/insert/). I.e. for every insertion, the place where the element is added is already known, thus constant time.

E.g. `list::push_front(element)` is short for `insert(begin(), element)`.

Answer (score 0):

[That's mostly a comment, but it didn't fit in the margin]

Note that an `std::list` **cannot** be implemented as a single linked list to fulfill the complexity requirements:

- Even when you already have an handle to a node of a **single linked list, you cannot insert before it (resp. erase it) in constant time** (since you would need access to the previous node).

That's why `std::forward_list` only provides `insert_after` and `erase_after`.